# Returning JsonArray from lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to get data from the database and return the results to another method. But I get this enclosing scope must be final error. Can someone please help me resolve this issue. I have attached screen shot of my code and error line.Thanks
Cheers
Zolf[image]

Comment: you should read about async programming, do not try to write code before reading/watching guides explaining differences between async and sync programming or you will struggle a lot and in the end hate async/reactive programming :) read about promises, non blocking code, lambdas etc, understand where async programming shines

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, can you please refer me to some good resource on async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an object within an enclosing scope in your code. To do so, you must make the `JsonArray` object constant. The `final` keyword in Java is used to declare a constant value. So, the error says that you must finalize ( make constant) the `resultData` object in order to use it inside that `connection.query` scope.
So, just add the `final` keyword before `JsonArray` in line 60 of your code:

```java
final JsonArray resultData = new JsonArray();
```

UPDATE:
If you cannot declare it as final, you need to use an workaround as mentioned in [this](https://www.netjstech.com/2015/09/resolving-local-variable-defined-in-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-or-effectively-final-error.html) blog.
You can declare an array of type JsonArray with a size of 1 and then change or use the value at the 0th position of the array. In this way, the object would be declared final without any harm.
In line 60, declare `final JsonArray[] resultData = { new JsonArray() };`
Then, use `resultData[0]` wherever you wish to use the value or change the value `resultData[0] = value;`. It also uses a single int data type value, so no extra memory would be used.

Here is the edited code that you can use:

```java
@Override
public JsonArray fetchAllPages*JDBCClient dbClient) {
    LOG.fo("INSIDE fetchAllPages method ");

    final JsonArray[] resultData = {new JsonArray()}; //created an array of type JsonArray
    dbClient.getConnection(ar->{
        if(ar.failed()) {
            LOG.error("Could not open a database connection",ar.cause());
        } else {
            SQLCollection connectionh = ar.result();
            connection.query("select * from test",rs->{
                if(rs.failed()) {
                    LOG.error("Database preparation error",rs.cause());
                } else {
                    for(JsonArray line:rs.result().getResults()) {
                        System.out.println("Table result: "+line.encode());
                        resultData[0]=line; //replaced resultData with resultData[0]
                    }

                    connection.close(done->{
                        if(done.failed()) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(done.cause());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return resultData[0]; //replaced resultData with resultData[0]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. In fact that was the first thing I did, but it gave me another error  saying _The final local variable resultData cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment_

Comment: You should have mentioned the whole problem in your question. See my edit.

Comment: the database is returning around 100 records and I need to capture it in the for loop on line 74 and then return the JSONArray

Comment: Thanks for your help!!. resultData is null when I return it and another issue is I need to send all the 100 values in the resultData array but now it is only returning the 0 index.